# Change the value of final Integer variable

Tags: java, class, integer, final

A `final` object cannot be changed, but we can set its attributes:

```
final MyClass object = new MyClass();
object.setAttr("something");              //<-- OK
object = someOtherObject;                 //<-- NOT OK
```

Is it possible to do the same with a `final Integer` and change its `int` value?

I'm asking because I call a worker:

```
public SomeClass myFunction(final String val1, final Integer myInt) {

    session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(...) {
        //Use and change value of myInt here
        //Using it requires it to be declared final (same reference)
    }
}
```

And i need to set the value of `myInt` inside of it.

I can declare my `int` inside another class, and that would work. But I wonder if this is necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No : an `Integer` is immutable, just like for example `String`.

But you can design your own class to embed an integer and use it instead of an Integer :

```
public class MutableInteger {
    private int value;
    public MutableInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have used String instead of Number, since he has used it in his example :D too picky, I know :D but a great short answer

Comment: You can simplify that by making `value` public. This is crappy but efficient. Then, you will access `myMutableIntegerObj.value` (e.g. from an inner class). +1 for @dystroy

Answer (score 6):

You can't because it immutable by design.

You can set the value of an `int[]` or `Integer[]` or `AtomicInteger`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the value of `final` integer once assigned.. However, you can delay the assignment., i.e. : - You can only assign a `final` integer once.. You can do it either at the time of declaration, or in initializer block, or in constructor..

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your Integer in another object that is final and then 'replace' the Integer inside that wrapper object by another.