# How to use variables of a method in the Mouse event class?

Tags: java, button, mouseevent, javafx-8

I have a code in javafx like this,

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author deb-l-ana
 */
public class NewFXMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root=new Group();
        Scene scene=new Scene(root,500,500,true);
        int ctr=0;
        Button b1=new Button("b1");
        b1.setTranslateX(90);
        root.getChildren().add(b1);
        b1.setOnAction(e -> {
            ctr=1;
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

This gives me a compilation error

> Local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

But if I declare `ctr` as final I cannot modify it. What can I do so that I can modify a local variable from a lambda expression? But if I use an array, `ctr1[]={0}` with a single element and then I could reference it from the lambda expression and this works fine.
 Why is this happening and how can I update the value of `ctr` from a mouse click event?

Comment: It should work. Please create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Move the variable `ctr` to an instance variable.

Answer (score -1):

I can't explain better than him : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12750186/5677103
"An Integer is immutable [...] but you can design your own class to embed an integer and use it instead of an Integer."

```
public class MutableInteger {
    private int value;
    public MutableInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

An instance of a final object can't be modified, but his attributes can be. Moreover, int is a privitive type and Integer an object that wraps this type.